# How to send and receive on one LwIP netconn socket asynchronously from several threads

Tags: freertos, lwip

I have a simple TCP (netconn) server on LWIP with FreeRTOS. It works fine in request - reply mode.
The server supports only one client connection, so one thread does accept and then serves the client.

Now I got a requirement to send asynchronously, from another thread.
That is, in addition to reply sent in the same thread, another thread will send unsolicited data to the client thru the same socket.

Can anyone point to example? Yes, I googled...

The LwIP FAQ says something about locking of TCP thread, but without any example. Is this locking required? If so, on both threads or only on the additional server thread?

My LwIP version is 2.0.3